# Escape special characters in a String

Tags: javascript

I have a String:
`c:\build\target`.

This comes from an external source, passed directly as it is. I cannot modify it before using it in a javascript.

However `\b` and `\t` are special characters, but I'd simply like to print it (or work with it) as it looks like, not as it is interpreted `c:uild            arget`.

How is it possible?

Comment: parse through the string and add another '\' whenever you need to

Comment: @GeneParmesan, why regex for such a simple task?

Comment: @GeneParmesan - That was my first thought, but by the time the string exists in Javascript it already has no backslash characters to match with the regex!

Comment: Too bad file systems don't just use '/' instead ...

Comment: If you are passing the string from the server to the client, does the client get the wrong string to begin with or is the string manipulated after?

Comment: The example given by @pfried below is what you have to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
string = "c:\build\target";
string = string.replace(/[\n]/g,'\\n');
string = string.replace(/[\r]/g,'\\r');
string = string.replace(/[\t]/g,'\\t');
string = string.replace(/[\b]/g,'\\b');
string = string.replace(/[\f]/g,'\\f');
console.log(string);​
```

But there maybe some other problems, because you have to catch all the other special chars

Comment: I think this would work. But how to escape the backslash simply to slash?

Comment: Oh sorry, i edited it, there could be a much better solution by getting all the characters in one catch, but i have to try a bit first

Comment: No, no, it was perfect. But if the string is `c:\build\target\other\xxx` then it would be nice to retain the other slashes as well :)

Comment: i'm getting doubts if this works for all chars, i tried to catch the char and save it so it could be done with one regex, but unfortunately some chars catch more than one "char" since \s is all the whitespace chars

Comment: But is it possible to catch simply `\\`?

Comment: no this is not possible since all these \a-z are special chars which are one character, to catch them i would need a function catching all the special chars in it, but then replace them by what char? it must be the backslash + correct letter

Answer (score 3):

Using a single regex replace (instead of many) is quicker and avoids errors related to the replace order.

```
console.info('c:\build\target'); // cuild   arget

console.info(escape('c:\build\target')); // c:\build\target

function escape(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\b\f\n\r\t\v\0\'\"\\]/g, match => {
    return {
      '\b': '\\b',
      '\f': '\\f',
      '\n': '\\n',
      '\r': '\\r',
      '\t': '\\t',
      '\v': '\\v',
      '\0': '\\0',
      '\'': '\\\'',
      '\"': '\\\"',
      '\\': '\\\\'
    }[match]
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to escape every backslash (so it's interpreted as a literal backslash).

If you can't do this on the remote system itself, you'll need to do this as the data is being parsed in Javascript.  Obviously once you already *have* a Javascript string, the backslashes are already missing.

So at the point where you go from "remote string" (which includes a `\` character followed by a `b`) to "Javascript string" (which includes a `\b` unprintable character), you'll need to keep an eye out for backslashes.  And ensure they're passed through as a literal backslash (i.e. escaped), rather than as an escape prefix.